# While loop finding the last iteration only

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

***How to solve this..??**

*My while loop is finding the last iteration only, If I select last attendance A then all the student's values will be **0**, if I select P then all the values will be **1**. So, how can I solve this?**

Index.php file

```
<?php 
include'connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Attendance</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id = $row['stu_id'];
        ?>
       <tr>
          
 <td><?php echo $row['stu_id'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
 <td>
     <form action="attendance.php" method="post">
         
     <select name="atten" id="">
         <option value="1">P</option>
         <option value="0">A</option>
     </select>
 </td>
       </tr>
       

<?php
    }  
?>

</table>

<br>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

attendance.php

```
<?php
include'connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `student_info`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(isset($_POST['atten'])){
        $atten = $_POST['atten'];
        
       echo $atten.'<br>';
    }
}
```

**Here is output**
[Image for Index.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyNMf.png)

[Image for attendance.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKkWA.png)

Comment: Your attendance loop is iterating through all of the student info, but only echoing the $_POST value. It's not echoing anything from the database, or limiting anything.

Comment: You also never close your form inside of the cell, nor do you have a button to submit

Comment: what should i do now..?

Comment: Can you please solve this..?

Answer (score 0):

You're not submitting the student ID in the form. You can use a hidden input for this.

```
<?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $id = $row['stu_id'];
        ?>
       <tr>
          
 <td><?php echo $row['stu_id'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
 <td>
     <form action="attendance.php" method="post">
     <input name="stu_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['stu_id'];?>">
     <select name="atten" id="">
         <option value="1">P</option>
         <option value="0">A</option>
     </select>
     </form>
 </td>
</tr>
<?php
}  
?>
```

Then in `attendance.php` you can update that student.

```
<?php
include'connection.php';
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE `student_info` set atten = ? WHERE stu_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $_POST['atten'], $_POST['stu_id']);
$stmt->execute();

echo "Attendance for student {$_POST['stu_id']} updated";
```

Comment: Yes, i can update.. But my concern is not update the student details,, i want to take attendance for all Student’s by using a loop so that i can take all at a time..

Comment: Each row contains just one form, so just one student. If you want to update all students you need to put the form around the entire table, and use an array of inputs.